# Material style is not visible when blender model is exported and used in threejs using glTF2.0

Tags: materials, three.js

I am new to both blender and threejs. I want to export and use a model developed in blender. I am using glTF2.0 to export this model. The following image is the rendered view of the model I want to use.[image]

Following options are enabled while exporting

[image]
[image]

But when I load this model in threejs by using following code

```
loader.load('models/neuron.gltf',
        function ( gltf ) { 
            scene.add( gltf.scene);
        },function ( xhr ) {
            console.log( ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
        },function ( error ) {
            console.log( 'An error happened' );
        }
    );
```

An end result is a 3D object without any material
[image]

But I want my model to show materials also.  Help me display models with materials from blender.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: You'll need to tell us something about the materials that are failing to appear — Cycles Nodes? Blender Render materials? Can you share a screenshot or the `.blend` file itself, ideally? Assuming you're using the Khronos Group exporter, see https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/blob/master/docs/user.md

Comment: My blend file is here - https://expirebox.com/download/8183231d1fdddd996a7d27683c9721cd.html